# await member.add_roles() not adding roles

Tags: discord.py

Im trying to make a mute command which mutes the user mentioned (obviously) and creates the muted role if no muted role was found. For some reason the add role parts arent adding the roles with no error returned.
This is the code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles = True)
async def mute(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    member = discord.Member
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = "Muted")
    if discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = "Muted"):
        await ctx.send("Role already exists")
        await member.add_roles(mute_role)
        await ctx.send("Muted")
    else: 
        await guild.create_role(name = "Muted", color = discord.Color(0x000001))
        await ctx.send("Created Role")
        await member.add_roles(mute_role)
        await ctx.send("Muted")
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not telling the bot what member to mute. `member = discord.Member` will not get you a member.

Try something like mentioning a member, and that member who gets mentioned get's muted. If you want to avoid mentioning a member, you can copy their ID and paste that as well.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles = True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    guild = ctx.guild
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = "Muted")
    if discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = "Muted"):
        await ctx.send("Role already exists")
        await member.add_roles(mute_role)
        await ctx.send("Muted")
    else: 
        await guild.create_role(name = "Muted", color = discord.Color(0x000001))
        await ctx.send("Created Role")
        await member.add_roles(mute_role)
        await ctx.send("Muted")
```

`(ctx, member: discord.Member)` tells the bot we have one argument, and that argument is a `discord.Member`. After that you don't need any `member =`  in your command. Any use of member will be the mentioned user (or the ID you paste)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
#and do this

ROLE = Muted

#You Could Do : 

role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name=ROLE)

#and instead of `await member.add_roles(mute_role)`

#Try

await member.add_roles(role)
```